# Как добавить комментарии к архиву? через сам Winrar

Tags: rar, winrar

Подскажите можно ли при помощи самого Winrar'a добавить комментарии к архиву?
Имеется такой вот скрипт для создания архива:
`WinRAR a -ep1 -r C:\Users\Antlion\Desktop\ZipDot.rar D:\Projects\Programs\ZipDot`

Мне нужно добавить комментарии к моему архиву, как это можно реализовать?

Я пробовал реализовать через команду: `C` не получилось. Типо:
`WinRAR a -ep1 -r C:\Users\Antlion\Desktop\ZipDot.rar D:\Projects\Programs\ZipDot c comment`

Есть вот такая вот команда через `.bat` файл для записи комментария в архив уже после создания:

```
<nul># set/p.=comment&start/wait WinRAR c C:\Users\Antlion\Desktop\ZipDot.rar -z#&&del #
```

Но можно ли сделать в одной команде всё это? Именно при создании.

Comment: https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPArcComment.htm